# RewriteRule getting error on files loaded

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But, if I enter in any page o my site, the scripts show an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This error occurs because in scripts files the content is replaced by HTML code and I don't know why.

If I enter in `https://somesite.com/Alex/` works fine, and if I enter in `https://somesite.com/users.php?q=Alex` works too, but, I want to when I access `https://somesite.com/users.php?q=Alex` replace the URL to `https://somesite.com/Alex/`.

So, how to do to fix the errors and to do it work?

Comment: Your second and third example URLs appear identical.

Comment: Yes @NathanTuggy , I want to when I access `https://somesite.com/users.php?q=Alex` replace the URL to `https://somesite.com/Alex/`.

Comment: I think you need to give a clearer example of how your HTML pages are being mangled. This doesn't sound like something that mod_rewrite would do.

Answer (score 1):

Use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /users\.php\?q=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ users.php?q=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Tested on Apache 2.4

Comment: @Igor sorry ,there was a typo in %{THE_REQUEST} variable name , I have corrected it. Please try the updated answer.

Comment: thanks, the error with scripts worked now! But, when I enter in `https://somesite.com/users.php?q=Alex` hte URL isn't replaced by `https://somesite.com/Alex/` :( and, can you explain me what you do to fix the erros with scripts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, short and sweet...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([.*]+)/$    users.php?q=$1    [QSA,L]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's usually wise to include the `RewriteCond` directives to check that the request is not a real file or directory, otherwise you make it impossible for users to request real directories so, for example, a real sub-directory called `mysite.com/articles` would become inaccessible.

Comment: @Bobulous - So, what your saying is... If I do not put this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in my htaccess file, people cannot go directly to a directory on my site or that a link to mysite.com/test/ will not function? The directory "test" is inaccessible?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The `RewriteRule` will see "test" and silently rewrite the request to "users.php?q=test" because there has been no `RewriteCond` to check that "test" is not a real directory. Bear in mind that even with the `RewriteCond` in place you might have a user choose the name "test" and then they would not be able to visit their profile with the tidy URL because then they'd be taken to the actual directory "test". For this reason, you'll notice that often these "SEO friendly" rewrites use the path "/users/test" to make it clear that this is a username and not a directory.